# Can someone please explain this definition of a "Random Variable" to me in laymans terms?

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

The above picture is the definition of a random variable, which I have trouble understanding. Could someone please explain this in laymans' terms?

Comment: I want to know what is your understanding so far based on this definition.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that no measurability is required? :)

Comment: I get lost at "X is a function from the sample space $\Omega$ to the real numbers $R$". This is saying that the function of a random variable will always map to be a real number? Idk.

Comment: Random variables assign real numbers to outcomes of experiments.

Answer (score 3):

The sample space $\Omega$ models the collection of all possible *outcomes* of a random experiment.

In practice, though, we often don't care about $\Omega$, for at least two reasons:

**1. The outcomes might not be encoded as numbers, and you can't do arithmetic with things that aren't numbers!**

For example, suppose you sit around with a group of three friends, John, Paul, and Ringo, sitting in a circle, and you place a bottle in the center, and then you spin it, and whomever the bottle points to has to sing a Beatles song. The easiest way to represent $\Omega$ here is a set of five possible outcomes, based on who the bottle points to:

$$\Omega=\left\{\text{you, John, Paul, Ringo, no one}\right\}$$

These aren't numbers! It doesn't make much sense to talk about the "average value" of the outcome of this experiment, because the outcomes aren't "values" we can "average"!

A random variable is a way of turning possibly non-numerical outcomes into real numbers. For example, consider the random variable $X$ defined on $\Omega$ that maps you to $1$, John to $2$, Paul to $3$, Ringo to $4$, and no one to $5$. It certainly does now make sense to ask for the "average value" of $X$, because at least the values of $X$ are numbers!

**2. Even if $\Omega$ is represented as a set of numbers, you might be interested only in a certain aspect of the set $\Omega$: you might not care about *all* the information it contains.**

Go back to the example above. Suppose you just care whether the bottle points to a person who was actually a member of The Beatles. For this problem, you might as well treat John, Paul, and Ringo as a single outcome, and you and no one as another outcome. So you could define the random variable $Y$ that maps John, Paul, and Ringo to $1$ but you and no one to $0$. Asking for the probability that $P(Y=1)$, for example, is then just code for asking for the probability that the bottle points to someone who was in the Beatles.

Answer (score 0):

As the definition states, a random variable is a *function* whose codomain is real numbers. For instance, consider the sample space $\Omega = [0,1]$, and the function $X(\omega)$ defined as follows:

$$X(\omega) = \begin{cases}
  1, & 0 \leq \omega < 1/6 \\
  2, & 1/6 \leq \omega < 2/6 \\
  3, & 2/6 \leq \omega < 3/6 \\
  4, & 3/6 \leq \omega < 4/6 \\
  5, & 4/6 \leq \omega < 5/6 \\
  6, & 5/6 \leq \omega \leq 1.
\end{cases}$$

It's a function in the ordinary sense; you tell me an input in the domain (such as $0.3$) and I can give you an output (such as $2$). You could graph this, if you wanted, and it would be a boring step function on the interval $[0,1]$.

Where this becomes meaningful is when we equip $[0,1]$ with a probability measure $\mathbb P$. Intuitively, we will give up control over the inputs, and we will instead let Tyche, goddess of fortune, choose the input. She will choose the inputs according to the measure $\mathbb P$. So if we (for instance) put the ordinary Borel measure on $[0,1]$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, then she will choose something in the interval $[1/2, 1]$ half the time, she will very commonly choose something in the interval $[0.1, 0.9]$, she will rarely choose something in the interval $[0, 0.001]$, and so on. Notice that with this framing, you can now see $X$ as a die roll, because it will be each of $\{1, \dots, 6\}$ with probability $1/6$.

After a particular $\omega$ is chosen, we plug it into $X$, and the output $X(\omega)$ is the realization of the random variable. Intuitively, we ask Tyche to choose an $\omega$, so she chooses $\omega = 0.953817$, which makes $X(\omega) = 6$, corresponding to rolling a die and having it land on $6$.

What makes it a random variable is the fact that it is rarely evaluated on particular inputs. Usually, all we do is talk about *distributions*, meaning we focus on questions of the form, "What is the measure (probability) of the subset of $\Omega$ that would cause $X$ to map onto the set $S$?" Generally, we just use a shorthand $\mathbb P(X \in S)$ for this. In the above example, if $S = \{3, 4\}$, then the collection of $\Omega$ that would cause $X$ to map there is $[2/6, 4/6)$, which has measure $2/6$. This is why we say the probability of rolling a $3$ or $4$ is $2/6$.

A final note: Notice that $\Omega$ wasn't actually that important at all. What if I'd used the sample space $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ itself, with a uniform probability measure (i.e. $\mathbb P(a) = 1/6$ for each $a$), and $X(\omega) = \omega$? Suddenly I'd have a function that functionally does the exact same thing as the first example, meaning that in some very real sense, it's *essentially the same random variable*.